# Sciptaculous number spinner

Tags: spinner, prototypejs, scriptaculous

does anybody know of the existence of a number spinner component compatible with prototype/scriptaculous? Something like [jQuery's spinner](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner).

I'm looking for nothing fancy, just numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example:

**HMTL**

```
<input id="spinner" type="text" value="0" readonly="readonly">
<div id="up">▲</div>
<div id="down">▼</div>
```

**Prototype 1.6**

```
$('up').observe('click', function() { $('spinner').value++; });
$('down').observe('click', function() { $('spinner').value--; });​
```

Detailed version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bmuF/) (with CSS already).

PS: only tested on firefox and chrome